# What could be causing my Shopify GraphQL mutation to return null when creating a product bundle?

Tags: graphql, shopify

I am trying to make bundle of products for my shopify store using GraphQL query when i run my below query it return product as null,
Here is my query

```
`mutation {
  productCreate(input: {
    title: "Our Product Bundle",
    handle: "bundle-product-1",
    productType: "Protective Equipment",
    vendor: "Powr Boxing",
    tags: "bundle",
    variants: [
      { price: 120, id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/39829539618929" },
      { price: 110, id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/39829539651697" },
      { price: 100, id: "gid://shopify/ProductVariant/39829539684465" }
    ]
  }) {
    product {
      id
      title
      handle
      productType
      vendor
      tags
      variants(first: 3) {
        edges {
          node {
            id
            price
          
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

// And Here is the response when i run my query 
`{
  "data": {
    "productCreate": {
      "product": null
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "cost": {
      "requestedQueryCost": 15,
      "actualQueryCost": 10,
      "throttleStatus": {
        "maximumAvailable": 1000,
        "currentlyAvailable": 990,
        "restoreRate": 50
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

can you suggest any solution or highlight where is the problem

I tried so many time but did not work search on google, read shopify documentation